# Manhwa about character who maxes out stats by repeating the first level?

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

Things I remember:

It was a manhwa, 100% Korean. Not sure if it was an isekai. The first level consisted of a dark passageway/tunnel, with different colored arrows/darts (not sure which) being shot at the MC. He discovered that every time he interacted with the projectiles (deflecting, catching, etc.), he would increase his stats.

IIRC the arrows/darts were different colors, each with different correlations. Red = ATK(?) Blue = speed? mana?? (not sure) Yellow = HP

The MC ended up repeating this first level so many times he was kind of OP by the time he actually left. I think he repeated the first level by buying special passes from the shop that allowed you to repeat the level, but were widely considered useless items as most people don't want to repeat levels and just move on. I can't remember what happens after this part to be honest... does anyone know of a manhwa that fits this description? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very similar question [was asked on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/d4nzu8/trying_to_remember_a_manhwa/).

> I need help remembering a manhwa.
>
> The details I remember are:
>
> The MC revived in the past I think
>
> He entered some kind of dungeon where he had to pass several levels, but he decided to repeat the first level in order to level up.
>
> The next level was full of ants and he got a vampiric dagger I think.

There, the answer was found to be *[Second Life Ranker](https://w3.secondliferanker.com/)*.

[image: Title cover of Second Life Ranker]

> Yeon-woo had a twin brother who suddenly disappeared 5 years ago. One day, he found a pocket watch belonged to his brother. When he opened it, he found the hidden diary in which was recorded the life of his brother in the Obelisk: the Tower of the Sun God, a world where several universes and dimensions intersect. His brother had fallen victim in this world to betrayal while climbing up the Obelisk. After learning the truth, Yeon-woo decided to climb the tower along with his brother’s diary.

[image: The first trap with "iron arrows"] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: Different methods of avoiding the arrows increases different stats] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

> Depending on how I deal with the arrows, there is a difference on which stat is increased.
>
> Dodging the blue arrow from the side will increase agility

It goes on to describe other methods increasing strength and stamina.

And yes, at the end of the first section, he sells the stats he's gained to buy 10 "Reset Tickets" that will let him restart the trap block (he notes after going through all 10 times that he can't afford to do that again because there is a time limit).

[image: The Reset Ticket] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Reddit post found with `manhwa "repeat the first level"`